# how do you prevent images from disappearing after adding mouse follow event in html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I had all of my images on the canvas, but then I added a mouse follow event, in which there is a circle following the mouse cursor. Once I added this new event, all of my images disappeared. What should I do in order to keep my images on the canvas along with the new mouse follow event? I tried adding the code for the images inside of the update function, but it still doesn't work... Any suggestions and solutions will be greatly appreciated!

```html
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700px" height="600px"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
var canvasPos = getPosition(canvas);
var mouseX = 700;
var mouseY = 600;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", setMousePosition, false);

function setMousePosition(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX - canvasPos.x;
  mouseY = e.clientY - canvasPos.y;
}

function update() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 35, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.fillStyle = "#eab4e4";
  context.fill();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();

//make mouse position values accurate
function getPosition(el) {
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;
 
  while (el) {
 if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
  //deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and pg scroll
  var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  
  xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
  yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
 } else {
  //for all other non-BODY elements
  xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
  yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
 }
 
 el = el.offsetParent;
 }
 return {
  x: xPos,
  y: yPos
 };
}  
  
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "MouseEvent/cheese 2.jpg";
myImage.addEventListener("load", loadImage, false);

var myImage2 = new Image();
myImage2.src = "MouseEvent/ballet mouse.jpg";
myImage2.addEventListener("load", loadImage, false);

var myImage3 = new Image();
myImage3.src = "MouseEvent/line.jpg";
myImage3.addEventListener("load", loadImage, false);

function loadImage(e) {
 context.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, 120, 120);
 context.drawImage(myImage2, 520, 400, 180, 200);
 context.drawImage(myImage3, 150, 200, 500, 220);
} 

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You will have to also run loadImage() inside update function, because clearRect is emptying the canvas.

Comment: I will try that out now.

Comment: I added the load image function just below the clearRect() method, but the images briefly appear and then vanish when the mouse event kicks in. Should I add the whole function or something simpler?

Comment: Try removing context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

Comment: When I remove that I do get everything to appear, but the circle follows the mouse and covers up the canvas meaning it does not clear out the circle previous positions.